# scrapy callback function not entered

Tags: scrapy

I have been searching for a solution for this, but none of those I found worked for me. After spending 2 days already debugging this, I should just ask you guys for help.

The urls look fine. Even I hard code a url before the request code, the callback function still not working.

My code is:

```
    def parse_link(self, response):
            print 'lllll', response.url
            print 'bbbbb', len(response.body), response.body

    def parse(self, response):
            hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
            issues = hxs.select('//a//@id').extract()
            for i in range(len(issues)):
                    issue = issues[i]
                    links_2d = hxs.select('//html//body//table[%d+%d]/tr/td//a[contains(text(),"full quotes")]/@href' % (9, i)).extract()
                    links_2d = list(set(links_2d))

                    if len(bb) < 1: continue
                    if len(links_2d) < 1: continue

                    full_link = links_2d[0]

                    yield scrapy.Request(url=full_link, callback = self.parse_link)
```

Comment: The allowed_domains etc.. have no problem.

Comment: where is the `link` object instantiated?

Comment: Sorry. That's my typo where I cleared my code before posting here. url=link should be url=full_link.

Comment: The problem is: even when I hard code a link in the Request function, say: url='http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.12/topics/request-response.html'. The parse_link still won't be entered.

Comment: what appears when you print full_link? please share some logs or something, like this it is very hard to help you

Comment: that is not a proper url, it is missing the schema

Comment: The url has no problem, i used correct url in Request function. When I add 'dont_filter=True' to the Request function, I got another error: Connection was refused by other side: 61: Connection refused. This is not an connection error or I am got banned by the website. Because when I directly crawl the url I hard coded, I can get everything.

Comment: aren't u sharing logs? I don't see any edits on your question

Comment: I tried Rules to follow the links as well, had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        issues = hxs.select('//a//@id').extract()
        for i in range(len(issues)):
                issue = issues[i]
                links_2d = hxs.select('//html//body//table[%d+%d]/tr/td//a[contains(text(),"full quotes")]/@href' % (9, i)).extract()
                links_2d = list(set(links_2d))

                if len(bb) < 1: continue
                if len(links_2d) < 1: continue

                full_link = links_2d[0]

                yield scrapy.Request(str(full_link), self.parse_link)

def parse_link(self, response):
        print 'lllll', response.url
        print 'bbbbb', len(response.body), response.body
```